# Value can't be deleted from the realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop an android app in which I can delete the value if it presents there. If value deleted it should give true and if value doesn't present there it should throw a false error. I am using a firebase realtime database.

I am trying to make an if-else statement but I can't succeed

```java
package com.vi.dhananjay.lol;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        Button eb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ebDelete);
        Button teac = (Button) findViewById(R.id.teaDelete);
        Button csd =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.conDelete);
        Button hosp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hosDelete);

        TextView qrCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);


        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            void deleDelete(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasChild("qrCode")) {
                    // run some code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        eb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ebDelete();
            }
        });
        teac.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    teacDelete();
            }
        });
        csd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    csdDelete();
            }
        });



        hosp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                hospDelete();
            }
        });

        del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleDelete();
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleDelete() {
        DatabaseReference qrcode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("delegates");
        qrcode.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void ebDelete() {
        DatabaseReference qrcode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("delegates");
        qrcode.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void teacDelete() {
        DatabaseReference qrcode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("delegates");
        qrcode.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void csdDelete() {
        DatabaseReference qrcode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("delegates");
        qrcode.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void hospDelete() {
        DatabaseReference qrcode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("delegates");
        qrcode.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Code validated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

The error which is arising

> error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onDataChange(DataSnapshot) in ValueEventListener

Answer (score 0):

When you implement `ValueEventListener`, you must implement both methods of that interface: `onDataChange` and `onCancelled`. It seems you changed the name of `onDataChange` to `deleDelete`, which means that the compiler can't find `onDataChange` anymore, leading to the error you get.

To fix the problem, rename `deleDelete` back to `onDataChange`:

```
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasChild("qrCode")) {
            // run some code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

---

If you'd like to use the `deleDelete` method name for clarity, you can include that in the implementation. You just need to ensure that you still implement `onDataChange`, as otherwise the compiler doesn't know what to do.

So something like:

```
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        deleteDelete(snapshot)
    }

    void deleteDelete(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasChild("qrCode")) {
            // run some code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

You'll note that `deleteDelete` is not tagged with `@Override` here, since it's not overriding/implementing a method from `ValueEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but I want to ask the value which comes in the TextView field which I have to send to the database how can insert them?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value from a text view? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354173/how-to-get-value-from-textview-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Yes, Sir! Getting values from the text view sending it to the database if that value presents then deleting if the value does not present then giving "False" reply.